# Jupyter Notebook extensions not running in conda environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda

I created a conda environment with a lower version of python to be able to run older packages on it. However, I found that I was not able to use jupyter notebook extensions like I used to. Whenever I try to enable something, I see a yellow box in the extensions window telling me it failed to load. [image]

I think this might be because I'm trying to run the jupyter server in the conda environment, but the notebook extensions are disconnected in some areas with this new environment. This is what I see when I run `jupyter nbextension list`

```
Known nbextensions:
  config dir: /media/rd3/usr_homes/username/.conda/envs/montage38/etc/jupyter/nbconfig
    notebook section
      nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main  enabled
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main
      jupyterlab-plotly/extension  enabled
      - Validating: OK
      jupyter-js-widgets/extension  enabled
      - Validating: OK
      contrib_nbextensions_help_item/main  enabled
      - Validating: OK
    tree section
      nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main  enabled
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main
  config dir: /media/rd3/usr_homes/username/.jupyter/nbconfig
    notebook section
      latex_envs/latex_envs disabled
      nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main  enabled
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main
      pydeck/extension  enabled
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X pydeck/extension
      jupyter-js-widgets/extension  enabled
      - Validating: OK
      contrib_nbextensions_help_item/main  enabled
      - Validating: OK
      vim_binding/vim_binding  enabled
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X vim_binding/vim_binding
      vim_binding  enabled
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X vim_binding
    tree section
      nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main  enabled
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main
  config dir: /usr/local/etc/jupyter/nbconfig
    notebook section
      nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main  enabled
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main
      contrib_nbextensions_help_item/main  enabled
      - Validating: OK
    tree section
      nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main  enabled
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main
```